# Find upcoming documents based on subdocument date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have some MongoDB Event documents, each of which has a number of sessions which take place on different dates. We might represent this as:

```
db.events.insert([
  {
    _id: '5be9860fcb16d525543cafe1',
    name: 'Past',
    host: '5be9860fcb16d525543daff1',
    sessions: [
      { date: new Date(Date.now() - 1e8 ) },
      { date: new Date(Date.now() + 1e8 ) }
    ]
  }, {
    _id: '5be9860fcb16d525543cafe2',
    name: 'Future',
    host: '5be9860fcb16d525543daff2',
    sessions: [
      { date: new Date(Date.now() + 2e8) },
      { date: new Date(Date.now() + 3e8) }
    ]
  }
]);
```

I'd like to find all Events which have not yet had their first session. So I'd like to find 'Future' but not 'Past'.

At the moment I'm using Mongoose and Express to do:

```
  Event.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$sessions' }, {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        startDate: { $min: '$sessions.date' }
      }
    },
    { $sort:{ startDate: 1 } }, {
      $match: { startDate: { $gte: new Date() } }
    }
  ])
    .then(result => Event.find({ _id: result.map(result => result._id) }))
    .then(event => Event.populate(events, 'host'))
    .then(events => res.json(events))
```

But I feel like I'm making heavy weather of this. Two hits on the database (three if you include the `populate` statement) and a big, complicated `aggregate` statement.

Is there a simpler way to do this? Ideally one which only involves one trip to the database.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)** to fold the array and find if any of of the elements have a past session.

To illustrate this, consider running the following aggregate pipeline:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "sessions.date": { "$gte": new Date() } } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "hasPastSession": { 
            "$reduce": {
                "input": "$sessions.date",
                "initialValue": false,
                "in": { 
                    "$or" : [
                        "$$value", 
                        { "$lt": ["$$this", new Date()] }
                     ] 
                 }
            }
       }
    } },
    //{ "$match": { "hasPastSession": false } }
])
```

Based on the above sample, this will yield the following documents with the extra field

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "5be9860fcb16d525543cafe1",
    "name" : "Past",
    "host" : "5be9860fcb16d525543daff1",
    "sessions" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-01-03T12:04:36.174Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-01-05T19:37:56.174Z")
        }
    ],
    "hasPastSession" : true
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5be9860fcb16d525543cafe2",
    "name" : "Future",
    "host" : "5be9860fcb16d525543daff2",
    "sessions" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-01-06T23:24:36.174Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-01-08T03:11:16.174Z")
        }
    ],
    "hasPastSession" : false
}
```

---

Armed with this aggregate pipeline, you can then leverage **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** and use the pipeline expression as your query in the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html)** method (or using the aggregate operation above but with the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline step at the end enabled) as

```
db.events.find(
    { "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
            false,
            { "$reduce": {
                "input": "$sessions.date",
                "initialValue": false,
                "in": { 
                    "$or" : [
                        "$$value", 
                        { "$lt": ["$$this", new Date()] }
                     ] 
                 }
           } }
        ]
    } }
)
```

which returns the document

```
{
    "_id" : "5be9860fcb16d525543cafe2",
    "name" : "Future",
    "host" : "5be9860fcb16d525543daff2",
    "sessions" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-01-06T23:24:36.174Z")
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2019-01-08T03:11:16.174Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this answered the question as the OP's query works but the OP used three queries and needs single query to simplify it. 1) Op's first query with aggregate is working 2) Op doesn't know about `$first` in group aggregation that's why he used second query to find the `host` key again. 3) Used populate as Op doesn't know about `$lookup`. But I cannot see anything related to it. Am I right?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet `$unwind` has a huge performance penalty cost attached especially unwinding all documents in the collection before matching the specific one(s) you actually want. The reason why `$unwind` is not as efficient is that it produces a cartesian product of the documents i.e. a copy of each document per array entry, which uses more memory (possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory) and therefore takes time to produce as well processing the documents during the flattening process. The answer above eliminates this bottleneck with just a single query

Comment: Ok but still can't see any join to connect the `host` field.

Comment: Well, the main question from OP is _I'd like to find **all Events** which have not yet had their first session. So I'd like to find 'Future' but not 'Past'._, the `host` populate can simply be done by chaining the `find()` method

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to find the `$min` date from the array. You can directly use [**`$min`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) to extract the min date from the `session` array and then use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to populate the `host` key

```
db.events.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "sessions.date": { "$gte": new Date() }}},
  { "$addFields": { "startDate": { "$min": "$sessions.date" }}},
  { "$match": { "startDate": { "$gte": new Date() }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "host",
    "localField": "host",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "host"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$host" }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you can just reach into the sessions of each event, and pull back each event where all session dates are only in the future? Something like this? Might need tweaking..

```
db.getCollection("events").aggregate(
    [

        {$match:{'$and':
               [
                   {'sessions.date':{'$gt': new Date()}}, 
                   {'sessions.date':{ '$not': {'$lt': new Date()}}} 
               ]
             }}
    ]
);
```